# How to return the result of a nested promise?

Tags: javascript, promise, ecmascript-6

I have two functions. One fetched users from a database and another loops through them and display them as a list:

```
store.findUsers = () => {
  function map (doc, emit) {
    if (doc.type === 'user') {
      emit(doc.createdAt)
    }
  }
  return db.query(map, {include_docs: true}).then(posts =>
    _.map(posts.rows, (post) => post.doc)
  )
}

store.getUserList = () => {
  store.findUsers().then(posts => {
    return _.map(posts, (post) => post)
  }).then(result => {
    return result
  })
}
```

I'm using the function like this:

```
var userList = store.getUserList()
console.log('User list:', userList)
```

However, `console.log('User list:', userList)` doesn't output anything. I think that's because `return result` in `store.getUserList()` is inside the nested promise.

How to modify the code to return `result`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't return it; that's not how promises work, and would pretty much defeat the purpose of them. Modify your function so that it returns a promise:

```
store.getUserList = () => {
  return store.findUsers().then(posts => {
    return _.map(posts, (post) => post)
  }).then(result => {
    return result
  })
}
```

and then use that promise whenever you call your function:

```
store.getUserList().then( userList => {
    console.log('User list:', userList);
} );
```

You can also simplify `store.getUserList` at lot. `.then(result => { return result } )` doesn't do anything so you can delete it, and in fact your map is being passed the identity function so it does nothing either. That whole function definition is equivalent to `store.getUserList = () => store.findUsers();`, which seems like a pretty useless function when you could just call `store.findUsers();` directly instead, and use it like this:

```
store.findUsers().then( userList => {
    console.log('User list:', userList);
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

So, the key here is to not return anything. You have no idea when the promise will come back, so returning doesn't mean much because the code won't wait for your promise.

Instead of a return, call another function within the promise's callback to do whatever it is you want to do:

```
doSomething.then((myData) => {
  somethingToDoWithData(myData);
});
```